How can charge neutrality be maintained for a forward-biased PN junction?
When a PN junction is forward biased, majority electons diffuse into p region and majority holes diffuse into n region, if we impose quasi-neutrality, then we have that in the p and n regiosn the change in majority carrier concentration must follow the same profile of the change in minority carrier by injection. How can this be practically possible, where so the excess electrons in n region to compensate for excess holes come from?

This is very simple. In a pn-junction in forward bias, the n-region is connected to the voltage source by a so-called ohmic contact which provides electrons from the negative electrode of the voltage source. When minority holes are injected into the n-region from the p-region, quasi-neutrality in the n-region is maintained by additional majority electrons supplied by the negative electrode of the voltage source. Similarly in the p-region, additional majority holes are provided by the positive electrode to neutralize the injected minority electrons.

I thought of this but didn't find any mentioning of the ohmic contacts in Neamen regarding this point. Thank you for clarifying this!

@Marcus Hany Practically all semiconductor devices need ohmic contacts to connect them electrically with the metal leads of the circuits where they are used in.

Just to be sure that I understand everything correctly, electrons only are injected from n to p region, and holes only are injected from p to n region. But the increase in electrons and holes in n and p regions respectively is due to supplying the excess amount from external circuit (ohmic contacts). Is that true?

@Marcus Hany You are right! This happens for any current flowing through a device with contacts.
